# Green functions in QFT

Tags: scattering, greens-functions, s-matrix-theory

What is the sense of Green function
$$
\langle | \hat {T}(u_{1}(x_{1})...u_{n}(x_{n})\hat {S})|\rangle , \quad \hat {S} = \hat{T}e^{i\int \hat {L}(x)d^{4}x} ?
$$
How is it connected with scattering processes?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)? In what context did you encounter the particular Green's function you write there? What are the $u_i$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : $u_{i}$ refers to the field functions. I know the mathematical sense of the Green function, but I want to know what is the physical sense of the function above. The Green's function above was given in paragraph about full Green's functions of QFT book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Green's function you have given arises as one step in the computation of elements of the S-matrix in the [LSZ-formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_formalism), if one considers the S-matrix in the interaction (or Dirac) picture.

Our goal is to compute scattering amplitudes of the form $\langle \prod_i p_i, \mathrm{in} | \prod_j q_j,\mathrm{out}\rangle$. In the course of the computation, we reduce this to the *n-point function* of the full Heisenberg fields $\langle \Omega | \hat T\prod_{k} \phi(x_k)| \Omega\rangle$. Switching to the interaction picture, we relate the Heisenberg fields to the interaction field through the time evolution operator $\hat U(t_1,t_2)$ fulfilling the relation $\mathrm{i}\partial_t \hat U(t_1,t_2) = \hat H_I(t_1)\hat U(t_1,t_2)$ which is solved by the *Dyson series*

$$ U(t,t_0) = \sum_n (-\mathrm{i})^{n} \int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{d}t_1 \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathrm{d}t_2 \dots \int_{t_0}^{t_{n-1}} \mathrm{d}t_n \hat H_I(t_1)\dots\hat H_I(t_n) = \\\sum_n \frac{(-\mathrm{i})^{n}}{n!} \int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{d}t_1 \int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{d}t_2 \dots \int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{d}t_n \hat T(\hat H_I(t_1)\dots\hat H_I(t_n)) = \hat T \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\int_{t_0}^t H_I(t')\mathrm{d}t'}$$

This is essentially your $\hat S$, only that instead of the Lagrangian density we have the Hamiltonian density (I don't know a case where the Lagrangian appears from the top of my head).

In the interaction picture, one finds (after a tedious calculation) that

$$ \langle \Omega | \prod_{k} \phi(x_k)| \Omega\rangle = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\langle 0 |\hat T \prod_k \phi_I(x_k)\hat U(-T,T)|0\rangle}{\langle 0 | \hat U(-T,T)|0\rangle}$$

This way, the function you have given is (up to normalization) essentially an n-point function, which in turn is essentially a scattering amplitude.

The entire computation and reasoning can be found in any decent QFT book, I have only tried to motivate the appearence of this term. Please let me know if you want more detail on something (or if this wasn't helpful at all).

**EDIT**: You are right, the $|p,\mathrm{out}\rangle$ states are fock states in the asymptotic Hilbert spaces. But, inverting the mode expression for the free field, one finds that

$$a_{in}(\vec{p}) = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2E_q}}\int \mathrm{d}^3x \mathrm{e}^{iqx}\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\phi_{in}(x)$$

where $x^0$ is arbitrary (this is another tedious calculation) and $f \overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0} g := f(\partial_0 g) - (\partial_0 f)g $. By this, you can write

$$\langle \Omega,\mathrm{in} | p,\mathrm{out}\rangle = \sqrt{2E_p}\langle \Omega,\mathrm{in} | a_in(p) | \Omega,\mathrm{out}\rangle = -\mathrm{i}\int\mathrm{d}^3 x\mathrm{e}^{ipx}\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\langle \Omega |\phi_{in}(x)|\Omega \rangle$$

. By repeatedly applying this, you can reduce the question of $\langle \prod_i p_i, \mathrm{in} | \prod_j q_j,\mathrm{out}\rangle$ to the n-point functions.

Comment: But why $in-, out-$ states refer to some fields, not only to creation/destruction operators? I thought that $\langle out | in \rangle$ refers to the $\langle out_{free} | \hat {S} | in_{free} \rangle$, where $out_{free}- , in_{free}$-states are only Fock basis states.